# iOS inter app communication to authenticate the other app's login

Tags: ios, authentication

I am trying to make an app which would communicate with my other app. It should work like the Facebook app and facebook messenger.

I have an app already installed and logged in with username and password authenticated. I installed another app from my organization which would have a login screen. I would like to automatically authenticate this second app with the credential of the first app.

Could someone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats the specific issue you are having? have you read up on and experimented with inter app communication?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html

Answer (score 0):

One possibility dont know really works or not, using URL schema.
Check if app is installed if yes then fire a web service which will send  device token for asking if any user is logged on this device currently if yes then use same name and pass from your server help.